# Apple Watch App Not Installing on Device or Simulator

Tags: watchkit, xcode7, watchos-2

Here is the warning that I get.

```
<App Name> was rejected as an implicit dependency for '<App Name>.app' because it doesn't contain platform 'iphonesimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'watchsimulator, watchos'
```

The app just sit there waiting to run an not installing on the device or simulator.

I am running Xcode 7 beta 2 and targeting watchOS 2.

This seems to happen right after I clean my project.